# Using Mobile Atlas Creator to create offline map

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am trying to create offline map for my Android application. I use Mobile Atlas Creator. I followed all instructions in the read me file and [here](http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30). But when I run `mobile atlas creator.exe` on my Windows, I don't see map in the pane. I choose the map source to `OpenStreetMap Mapnik`. I prepare the map compatible for `Osmdroid ZIP`. What could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: MOBAC is now blocked from using OSM servers, see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Blocked_applications

Comment: @NickT; Thanks. The alternative way is shown here (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android). These are Android app. How can I make offline Map using OpenStreetMap?

Comment: The only way I knew was to use MOBAC. I haven't investigated rendering my own tiles yet.

Comment: You mean we can render our own tiles also? How to do that?

Comment: I don't know as I haven't investigated how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old versions of MOBAC violated the OSM Tiles usage policy and so it was blocked https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mobile_Atlas_Creator
I'm not sure about recent versions, but maybe they will keep blocked.

There are various other tools for downloading tiles in a comform way: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Category:Tile_downloading
You can also create your own tiles using a desktop renderer as [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) or you can [setup your own rendering stack](http://www.switch2osm.org) local or remote.

Answer (score 0):

MOBAC Version 2.0.0 beta 3 (2350) works again. You can get it here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mobac/

For me a simple way to download OSM-based tiles. Few tile sources but a lot of export formats.